# Why does callback fail after uploading image to Blobstore?

Tags: java, android, servlets, http-post, blobstore

I am trying to upload photos to blobstore. The photo gets uploaded succesfully to blobstore but I cannot get the blobkey and servingUrl back. I tried debugging and saw that callback is not made to BlobUpload.java. It gives an error 'Connection to http:// localhost:8888 refused' I am confused because BlobUrlGet.java invokes with no problem and the photo is uploaded. I tried every type of url for the server and the servlets, none of them worked.

**EDIT:** I realised that if I manually change the 'localhost:8888'  to '10.0.2.2:8888' in the debug mode (str variable), 'connection refused' problem goes away but this time it shows below error.

http:// localhost:8888/_ah/upload/ahFteWZpcnN0YXBwZGVtbzEyM3IiCxIVX19CbG9iVXBsb2FkU2Vzc2lvbl9fGICAgICAgN4KDAError 405 HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

### Error 405 HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

This is the return from post method. It is the same error when I deploy to appengine and work from there.

My code is as below.

BlobUrlGet.java

```
public class BlobUrlGet extends HttpServlet{   
    BlobstoreService blServ = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();    
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {  
        String blobUploadUrl = blServ.createUploadUrl("/blob");   
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");    
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.print(blobUploadUrl);
    }       
}
```

BlobUpload.java

```
public class BlobUpload extends HttpServlet {
    BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory
            .getBlobstoreService();

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        try {
            List<BlobKey> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(req).get("file");
            BlobKey blobKey = blobs.get(0);

            ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory
                    .getImagesService();
            ServingUrlOptions servingOptions = ServingUrlOptions.Builder
                    .withBlobKey(blobKey);

            String servingUrl = imagesService.getServingUrl(servingOptions);

            resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            resp.setContentType("application/json");

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

            json.put("servingUrl", servingUrl);
            json.put("blobKey", blobKey.getKeyString());

            PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
            out.print(json.toString());
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Android client

```
private class GetBlobUrlTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0){  

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();    
        //This will invoke "ImgUpload servlet           
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://10.0.2.2:8888/bloburl"); 
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);         
            HttpEntity urlEntity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream in = urlEntity.getContent();
            String str = ""; 
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            String encoding = "UTF-8";
            IOUtils.copy(in, writer, encoding);
            str = writer.toString();
//              str = URLDecoder.decode(str, "UTF-8");
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(str);
                File f = new File(picturePath);
                FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(f);
                MultipartEntityBuilder reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
                reqEntity.addPart("file", fileBody);
                reqEntity.addBinaryBody("Photo", f, ContentType.create("image/jpeg"), "foto2.jpg");
                httppost.setEntity(reqEntity.build());
                response = httpClient.execute(httppost); //Here "uploaded" servlet is automatically       invoked
                urlEntity = response.getEntity(); //Response will be returned by "uploaded" servlet in JSON format
                in = urlEntity.getContent();
                str = "";
                IOUtils.copy(in, writer, encoding);
                str = writer.toString();
                JSONObject resultJson = new JSONObject(str);
                blobKey = resultJson.getString("blobKey");
                servingUrl = resultJson.getString("servingUrl");    



        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
```

web.xml

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>BlobstoreURL</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.samplesolutions.mobileassistant.BlobUrlGet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>BlobstoreURL</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/bloburl</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>BlobstoreUpload</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.samplesolutions.mobileassistant.BlobUpload</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>BlobstoreUpload</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/blob</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

doPost should have been overridden. Now it works perfectly.

```
public class BlobUpload extends HttpServlet {
    BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory
            .getBlobstoreService();
    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        try {
            List<BlobKey> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(req).get("file");
            BlobKey blobKey = blobs.get(0);
```